# Meteor find not returning data

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, iron-router

My collection is created in collections.js

```
portfolioCategories = new Mongo.Collection('portfoliocategories');
```

It is then subscribed to in subscriptions.js

```
Meteor.subscribe('portfoliocategories');
```

And published in publications.js

```
Meteor.publish('portfoliocategories',function(){
    return portfolioCategories.find();
});
```

If I query Mongo from the server with *db.portfoliocategories.find()* I'll get

> { "_id" : "W9AeauCpMgPw2j5hf", "title" : "Commercial Design", "slug" : "commercial-design", "image" : "https://url/9c3ba46d-c09a-4a7d-ac40-5752fc24ad2c.jpg" }

From the client and ironrouter both, however, find returns nothing. For example if I type into the console:

```
portfolioCategories.find({'_id':'W9AeauCpMgPw2j5hf'});
```

I will get a LocalCollection.Cursor with undefined key values:

> _selectorId: undefined
>
> _transform: null
>
> collection: LocalCollection
>
> fields: undefined
>
> limit: undefined

The same thing happens in iron-router if I try to return that as data. Yet, if I use findOne I'll get the document.

```
portfolioCategories.findOne({'_id':'W9AeauCpMgPw2j5hf'})
```

> Object { "_id" : "W9AeauCpMgPw2j5hf", "title" : "Commercial Design", "slug" : "commercial-design", "image" : "https://url/9c3ba46d-c09a-4a7d-ac40-5752fc24ad2c.jpg" }

*My issue is that I need to return all items with the the same title.* Because of this, findOne() is not a proper solution.

What am I missing?

Comment: [find](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/find) returns a cursor, on which you can call `fetch` to get an array of documents. A complete answer can be given with more details on how you want to use these documents.

Comment: So is proper syntax something more like `portfolioCategories.find().fetch()` ?

Comment: Another curiosity, however, is that what I'm trying to do works on other templates. For example `featuredItems: function () { return projectsPortfolio.find({'featured':true}); }` works just fine and as it should.

Comment: (a) yes that's the syntax if you want an array of documents, (b) yes, templates accept both cursors and arrays as inputs.

Comment: Thank you for working through this with me, my rubber duck was no help. I'll provide a follow answer as the real issue is a discrepancy in my understanding of iron-router's data object and template helpers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The confusion came because of the differences between iron-router's data object. What I was trying to do from iron-router was

```
waitOn:function(){

    return [Meteor.subscribe('projectsportfolio'),Meteor.subscribe('portfoliocategories')];

}
data:function(){
    currentSlug = this.params.category;
    currentCategory = projectsPortfolio.find({slug:currentSlug});
    if(typeof currentCategory != 'undefined'){
        return currentCategory
    }
}
```

But this only returns a cursor as @David Weldon explained. **The solution is:**

```
data:function(){
    currentSlug = this.params.category;
    currentCategory = projectsPortfolio.find({slug:currentSlug}).fetch();
    if(typeof currentCategory != 'undefined'){
        return currentCategory
    }
}
```

currentCategory will now be an array of objects that I can now loop through in my template as

```
{{#each currentCategory}}
    {{keyvalue}}
{{/each}}
```